# Confused about real polynomial ring generated by an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Claim: $(x)\neq \langle x \rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}[x].$

Notation:

$(x)$ is the principal ideal generated by x.

$\langle x \rangle$ is the same as in group theory, namely cyclic group generated by x.

My idea: Since the set of all polynomials with constant term $0$ is equal to $(x)$ and an ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ (I have proved this) and then showing that $\langle x \rangle$ is not an ideal, the above claim is true.

However, I am confused on what $\langle x \rangle$ is in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Is it just the set $\{x, 2x, 3x,..., nx\: \lvert n\in \mathbb{N}\}$? But isn't it generating the polynomial ring? What is it?

Comment: Not sure this is what you are looking for, but $x^2$ is in the ideal generated by $x$.

Comment: Isn't $\langle x \rangle = \Bbb Zx$ as an additive subgroup?

Comment: Then easy to see that $\sqrt 2 x \in (x), \notin \langle x \rangle$.

Comment: @xbh Not sure about your first comment since I'm dealing with real polynomials. Regarding your second comment, that's what I was thinking but I wasn't sure if I am interpreting $\langle x \rangle$ correctly.

Comment: Fun fact: $(a) = \langle a \rangle$ for all $a \in R$ if and only if $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with the usual operations (up to iso).

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, $\langle x \rangle$ is the set $\{x, 2x, 3x,...,nx,... \: \lvert n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. But $(x) = \{rx \lvert r\in \mathbb{R}[x]\}$. Then you can see that $x^2 \in (x)$,but $x^2\notin \langle x \rangle$ as mentioned in the comment. In general, $\langle x \rangle \subseteq (x) $.